# Backtick and tilde keys - Why the switch?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, locale

Most of the differences between European and US keyboards make sense for reasons of localisation. However, one thing I've always felt the US keyboards did better (and all EU keyboards I've used seem to have this flaw), is having the ~ symbol on beside the number 1. EU keyboards instead have the ` key in that spot. For me to type a tilde, I have to press shift+# which is beside the enter key, an awkard combination for a symbol I use rather frequently.

Uses of ~:

- Approx
- Home Directory on *x systems

Uses of `:

- Executing shell commands in PHP
- Escaping things on Stack Overflow and co.

Now as you can see, your likely to use your home directory on a command line more often that executing shell commands in PHP, and your about a billion times more likely to use approx than to escape something on SO/SF/SU.

Does anyone know the reason why these keys are switched?

Comment: maybe I am not reading the question properly, but on US keyboards, the key next to the 1 is also backtick.  It's only tilde if you press shift.

Comment: Ah, I had been led to believe that it was tilde first on US keyboards, because on all gaming forums talking about accessing consoles, I see the instructions say Press the tilde key (` for european keyboards).

Comment: Shift-Accent is also tilde for Australian keyboard layouts

Comment: What I want to know is what this weird ¬ character is on UK keyboards that one gets by typing SHIFT+backtick, and how does one get the broken pipe, which is the third symbol on that key?

Comment: @paradroid It's one possible symbol for not in logic. ¬A + ¬B would be (!a || !b)

Comment: If there's a third symbol on a key, you use Alt Gr to get it.

Comment: The # key is much closer to a Shift key than ` - doesn't that make ~ quicker to type on the UK layout than the US?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On US keyboards, <kbd>~</kbd> is the same as <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>. From what I can see, it looks like the opposite is the case on EU keyboards, so the functionality is practically the same. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Shift+` is ¬ on my UK keyboard. ~ is on Shift+# which is right beside the Return key on the asdf row.

Comment: @jtbandes: Your comment about EU keyboards is incorrect; Sam is correct. The key to the left of 1 is '`' (backtick); pressing shift gives '¬'. Also @Macha: this doesn't appear to answer your question, so why is it the accepted answer?

Comment: @Steve: hm, ok, thanks for clarifying. My guess, then, is that the Macha was looking for the "\`" on US keyboards, so this answered the question.

Comment: And by "the Macha" I meant "the OP" or "Macha", not a combination of both. `;)`

Comment: I was too quick to mark this as the accepted answer. After reading it, I assumed that Irish keyboards were different to the other European keyboards, aswell as the US ones. I hate un-accepting answers, but it is technically incorrect.

Comment: I think this is technically correct, but only for Mac computers. My Irish Mac keyboard behaves like the answer is stating.